# How to resolve 'faraday-net_http requires Ruby version >= 2.6.0' error when installing fluent-plugin-elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby, faraday, efk

I'm trying to run docker containers for EFK stack using docker compose.

[image: docker-compose.yml]

but it keeps throwing me this error :

[image: Error].

I tried to install the specified version of faraday-net_http using this command :

`gem install faraday-net_http -v 2.1.0` and checked my ruby version and it was : **ruby 3.0.2p107** .
I tried also to update rubygems using  `gem install rubygems-update` & `update_rubygems`but i'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Please do not post images, copy'n'paste relevant text formatted as code into your question. When I read the image correctly, it seems like you are trying to install and run Ruby 2.5.0 which reached end-of-life more than two years ago. I suggest updating to an up.to-date Ruby version which means: 3.1.4 or 3.2.2